# posts do not load after addind onAuthStateChanged

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic4

I recently added the onAuthStateChanged function  in constructor, and if the user is not null then i call a function to get the posts (events). But the data of the function does not load until i click somewhere in the page and then the data shows. There are no errors shown.

I tried clearing the onAuthStateChanged and the data loads OK, but i need to add the security of firebase in this page.

Here is my feed.ts , and the function getEvents()

```
public async getEvents() {
    this.events = [];
    const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Loading events...'
    });

    loading.present();
    const query = firebase.firestore().collection('events').orderBy('created', 'desc').limit(this.pageSize);

    query.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const changedDocs = snapshot.docChanges();

      changedDocs.forEach((change) => {
        if (change.type == 'modified') {
          for (let i = 0; i < this.events.length; i++) {
            if (this.events[i].id === change.doc.id) {
              this.events[i] = change.doc;
            }
          }
        }
      })
    })

    query.get().then((events) => {
      events.forEach((event) => {
        this.events.push(event);
      });

      loading.dismiss();
      if (events.size == 0) {
        this.cursor = 0;
      } else {
        this.cursor = this.events[this.events.length - 1]; // the last index of the collection
      }
      console.log(this.events);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Here is the constructon where i call the function getEvents(). The loading message shows when i open the app, but the data are not shown unless i click anywhere on the app.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private toastCtrl: ToastController, private http: HttpClient, public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public popoverCtrl: PopoverController, private location: Location, ) {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.getEvents();
      } else {
        this.location.replaceState('/');
        this.navCtrl.navigateForward('login');
      }
    });
    // this.getEvents();
  }
```

The function works fine if i call it outside the condition if(user) { ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just check [currentuser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#currentuser):

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private toastCtrl: ToastController, private http: HttpClient, public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public popoverCtrl: PopoverController, private location: Location, ) {
      if (firebase.auth().currentUser != null) {
        this.getEvents();
      }
}
```

I would use a router guard to block the user from the page rather than the redirect to login code you have put in there.

Comment: I have tried adding this, but this doesnt work because this does not detect the changes in authorization and if a dont logout and try te refresh this page, it throws an error sicne firebase does not let to access the user variables outside this onAuthStateChange function. 
Can i use route guard in combine with firebase? Does using angular route guard detects the user authentication of firebase?